# VB.net, cannot access OpenFileDialog that has been added to project

Tags: vb.net, openfiledialog

I have decades of experience writing VB6 apps but today I tried to write a simple VB.net app using Microsoft Visual Studio 2019. I fell at the first hurdle. I'm sure I'm doing something really simple wrong so forgive the naive question.

Using the toolbox, I added an OpenFileDialog object to my main (one and only) form. Unlike VB6, this didn't appear on the form but in a sort of bar along the bottom of the window, but it was definitely there and I was able to set some properties.

I then added a button and wrote my first line of code:
With OpenFileDialog1
Wrong! I get errpr BC30451: 'OpenFileDialog1' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

But I can see it sitting there in the design view, I have spelt its name correctly and the above code is
exactly copied from the example. I tried changing OpenFileDialog1's Modifiers property from Friend to Public - makes no difference.

What novice mistake have I made? How do I access an OpenFileDialog object that I have definitely added to my form?

Comment: Where are you trying to write this code? Did you add a handler to the Button.Click event and started writing your code there? Can you post what you have (all parts that allow to determine a clear context)?

Comment: Just tried to duplicate. I put the With statement in the New subroutine and in the Button_Click event and it works with no problems.

Comment: Getting late here. Will post some screenshots tomorrow

Comment: We don't want screenshots. We want the relevant code posted as text, formatted as code. We can't copy code from a picture. You can add a screenshot as well, if it adds some value, but NEVER post ONLY a screenshot of code. The same goes for error messages.

Comment: Can't see a way to add images here but if you look at http://writerman.org.uk/Design.png you will see the design view with OpenFileDialog1 in the bar along the bottom. http://writerman.org.uk/Code.png shows me trying to add code to a browse button and having With OpenFileDialog1 flagged as an error.
If I double click on OpenFileDialog1 in the bottom bit, it adds a OpenFileDialog1_FileOk routine so it clearly recognises it as part of the project.

Comment: Apologies for not realising screen shots not the thing but they do illustrate the problem. The code I am writing looks like this (not sure how to format when adding comment)
 Private Sub bBrowse_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        With OpenFileDialog1

        End With

    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs)

    End Sub

This is within the Public Class frmMain. Note the auto-added OpenFileDialog1_FileOk demonstrating that OpenFileDialog1 really exists

Comment: Sorry, that looks aweful. How do I format code when adding a comment?

Comment: It's worse than I thought. I cannot access ANY of the controls on my form. I have a text box called tbFile but if I write tbFile.Text it tells me tbFile isn't declared

Comment: Comments aren't really designed to include code.  If you need formatted code, it should be in your question (if from you) or in an answer (if from someone else).

Answer (score 0):

The FolderBrowserDialog which can be dragged onto the form using the toolbox, is out of date and offers (from today's perspective) too few options. Do yourself a favor and use the Nuget Package Manager to download the modern OpenFileDialog.

```
Imports Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs
```

in your *Private Sub Button1_Click*:

```
Dim Pfad As String
        Using OFD1 As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD1.Title = "Datei auswählen"
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("JPG", ".jpg"))
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("JPEG", ".jpeg"))
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("Bitmap", ".bmp"))
            OFD1.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("PNG", ".png"))
            OFD1.IsFolderPicker = False 'true to make it an FolderBrowserDialog ;-)
            OFD1.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            If OFD1.ShowDialog = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                Pfad = OFD1.FileName
            Else
                Return
            End If
        End Using
```

for Multiselect (with `Bildpfade1` as a New List(of String) ):

```
Using OFD As New CommonOpenFileDialog
            OFD.Title = "Bilder auswählen"
            OFD.Filters.Add(New CommonFileDialogFilter("JPG", ".jpg;jpeg"))
            OFD.Multiselect = True
            OFD.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)
            If OFD.ShowDialog() = CommonFileDialogResult.Ok Then
                For Each file As String In OFD.FileNames
                    Bildpfade1.Add(file)
                Next
            End If
End Using
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'd still like to understand why I cannot access a correctly added control. Is the control you recommend part of the standard, free, Dev Studio download?

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the answer but it looks, to me, like a bug in Visual Studio. I saved the project and closed Visual Studio. Restarted and reloaded the project. All the controls I had added to my form had vanished!

I rebuilt the now-empty project then started adding controls - lo and behold, I can now access all my controls from code whereas, previously, I couldn't access any of them. It looks like, prior to the initial build, none of the controls I thought I'd added had actually been added. Certainly they didn't survive save project, restart Visual Studio.

Seems to work now. Many thanks to those who contributed suggestions.

Comment: This is not a criticism but you should delete this question altogether. It's not useful to anyone else because it's not a reproducible issue.

Comment: It might be if someone else has the same issue but I take your point. However, when I tried to delete it, the system wouldn't let me saying "others have invested time and effort providing answers".